Are there any known G-type stars that have a flare star variable type?
G-type stars are not usually flare stars because most flare stars are M-type stars, and sometimes, late K-type stars. However, if a G-type star is young, it tends to be a flare star variable type. Are there any known examples of a G-type star that is a flare star variable type?

How about HD 39150 -- Eruptive Variable https://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=TIC+364588501&submit=SIMBAD+search https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.00993

Thank you so much.

I hesitate to call it a "flare star", since I can't find it described as such in the literature, but (for example) HD 39150 (Type GV3) is described as an "eruptive variable" and mentioned as an example of "Superflaring G-type Stars" under the catalogue identifier "TIC 364588501". And also in Superflares, Chromospheric Activities, and Photometric Variabilities of Solar-type Stars from the Second-year Observation of TESS and Spectra of LAMOST.
These may give examples of G type stars that produce extremely energetic flares, and so may provide examples of the type of star you are looking for.

Thank you very much for your answer.

If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the chrckmark.
